# Callout couldn't access the endpoint in Named Credentials in Managed Package

Tags: credentials, named

i am facing this issue,it is running correctly in my org but when I created managed package and installed in another org,it is showing the error.

```apex
public static String  getToken() {
        
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        return 'sImV4cCI6MTY5OTcyOTkyOCwiaXNzIjoiUmVhbGZpbkFQSSIsImF1ZCI6IlJlYWxmaW5BUElDbGllbnRzIn0';
    }
    System.debug('getToken: ' );
    String targetEndpointUrl = 'callout:Realfin_Credentials/token';

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setEndpoint(targetEndpointUrl);

    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('accept', 'text/plain');
    Map<String, String> requestBody = new Map<String, String>();
    requestBody.put('username', '{!$Credential.Username}');
    requestBody.put('password', '{!$Credential.Password}');
    String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(requestBody);
    System.debug('requestBody-------'+requestBody);
    System.debug('jsonbody-------'+jsonBody);
    req.setBody(jsonBody);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug('getToken res: ' +res);
    if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        if (responseMap !=null && responseMap.containsKey('token')) {
            authenticationKey=(String)responseMap.get('token');
        } else {
            //return null; 
        }
        
    } else {
        System.debug('API request failed IN Get Token with status code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
        System.debug('Response Body: ' + res.getBody());
    }
    System.debug('authenticationKey: ' + authenticationKey);
    return authenticationKey;
}
```